# sql to linq where statement with case

Tags: c#, sql, linq, stored-procedures

I have in my sp the following for the where statement :

```
            SELECT  h.HLDG_DATE,
                m.PTF_FIDEM_ID,
                m.PTF_Name,
                id.IDENTIFIER_NAME, 
                MIN(h.DESCRIPTION) DESCRIPTION,
                ii.SPEC_TABLE,
                m.PTF_CURRENCY, 
                id.IDENTIFIER_VALUE,
                h.CURRENCY,
                h.HLDG_QTY,
                MIN(h.CURRENT_PRICE) current_price,
                h.INSTRUMENT_ID
          FROM HOLDINGS_BREAKDOWN h
            LEFT JOIN FI_SYS_PTFIDX_LIST m on  (m.PTF_FIDEM_ID = h.PORTFOLIO_ID)
            LEFT JOIN inst_identifiers id on   (h.instrument_id = id.instrument_id)
            LEFT JOIN INST_CASH ic ON h.INSTRUMENT_ID = ic.INSTRUMENT_ID
            LEFT JOIN INST_FX_FORWARD iff ON h.INSTRUMENT_ID = iff.INSTRUMENT_ID
            LEFT JOIN INST_FX_SPOT ifs ON h.INSTRUMENT_ID = ifs.INSTRUMENT_ID
            JOIN INST_IDS ii ON h.INSTRUMENT_ID = ii.INSTRUMENT_ID
          WHERE h.PORTFOLIO_ID = 112
            AND h.HLDG_DATE >= '28 November 2014'
            AND  h.HLDG_DATE <= '31 December 2014'
            AND id.IDENTIFIER_NAME = (CASE WHEN ii.SPEC_TABLE 
                in ('INST_BOND','INST_EQUITY','INST_FUTURE') THEN 'ISIN'
                   WHEN ii.SPEC_TABLE ='INST_CASH' THEN 'XXX'   
                   WHEN ii.SPEC_TABLE = 'INST_INDEX_RETURN_SWAP' 
                    THEN 'BBG_UNIQUE' WHEN ii.SPEC_TABLE = 'INST_TOTAL_RETURN_SWAP'
                    THEN 'BBG_UNIQUE' ELSE 'STATESTREET'  END )
         GROUP BY h.HOLDING_PARAMS_ID,h.INSTRUMENT_ID, h.CURRENCY,id.IDENTIFIER_VALUE,h.HLDG_QTY,
                ii.SPEC_TABLE, h.HLDG_DATE,m.PTF_FIDEM_ID,m.PTF_Name,id.IDENTIFIER_NAME,m.PTF_CURRENCY 
         ORDER BY h.HLDG_DATE,Description  DESC
```

I have already done in linq:

```
 where  h.PORTFOLIO_ID == Convert.ToInt16(PfID)
         &&     h.HLDG_DATE >=Convert.ToDateTime(  DTstart)
         &&     h.HLDG_DATE <= Convert.ToDateTime(DTend)
```

I am struggling with the last condition with the "case" can you please help me on that ?

Comment: You need to show the rest of the query from the SP in order to identify what ii is in that context. Is it a joined table, a sub select etc...

Comment: What is the issue and which DBMS you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it may not genereate the same CASE statement, but the *functional* equivalent would be:

```
string[] isins = new [] {"I_BOND","I_EQUITY","I_FUTURE"}

...
where  h.PORTFOLIO_ID == Convert.ToInt16(PfID)
   &&  h.HLDG_DATE >= Convert.ToDateTime(DTstart)
   &&  h.HLDG_DATE <= Convert.ToDateTime(DTend)
   &&  id.IDENTIFIER_NAME == (
           inins.Contains(ii.SP_TABLE)            ? "ISIN" :
           ii.S_TABLE == "I_CASH"                 ? "CDB"  :
           ii.S_TABLE == "I_INDEX_RETURN_SWAP"    ? "BBG_UNIQUE"  :
           ii.S_TABLE == "INST_TOTAL_RETURN_SWAP" ? "BBG_UNIQUE"  :
           "STTREET");
```

Another alternative would be to put that mapping in a table and do a `JOIN` instead.

Note also that you may have to do the `Convert.ToXXX` calls outside of the Linq statement and store the results as variables so they get treated as constants by Linq.

Answer (score 0):

switch statements are not allowed in linq2sql as far as i know (please correct me, if that's wrong). This means, there is no direct way to write a statement, which will be translated to an SQL-Case.

I would recommend to just use the ternary operator `?:` to build the statement. This is not the most beautiful way, but totally ok in this case.

(BTW, another tip: Convert your dates outside of the linq-statement. When you do this, the statement ist converted by the .NET Framework and only the converted value will be passed to SQL, not the whole convert operation, which is quite expensive)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with something like this

```
var tables = new List<string>{"INST_BOND","INST_EQUITY","INST_FUTURE"};
.........
.. id.IDENTIFIER_NAME = tables.Contains(ii.SPEC_TABLE) 
                         ? "ISIN"
                         : ii.SPEC_TABLE == "INST_CASH" 
                            ? id.IDENTIFIER_NAME == "XXX"
                            :ii.SPEC_TABLE == "INST_INDEX_RETURN_SWAP"
                              ? "BBG_UNIQUE"
                               .........
```

That would be the literal translation, but you should rather create a logical structure, like a `dictionary` e.g. and assign that value after you execute the linq. If you want to use linq, then you'll need to have a look up table and do join with `ii.SPEC_TABLE`